# (Loading...) image inside accordion's div

Tags: jquery, load, accordion

I am using Jquery accordion divs and inside each div there is an iframe, where the iframe is linked to external page to show a chart from another server. I was just wondering if there is any way to display a loading image when the user click over the accordion’s header, or at least change the iframe text to "Loading.." while it is loading the chart.

Comment: Display a popup with loading image in it...

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-very-simple-popup-box-div

Comment: this is cool feature, but I did no ask for a popup. What I need is to preloading image instead popup div and it should disapear after the data is loaded...